# How to fund a 2nd master's degree (UK), or should I directly go for a PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, funding, united-kingdom

I will receive my master's degree soon. Even though it was a nice program, I found out I'm more interested in something else. Now, I'm thinking should I do another MSc (one-year) in the other field before starting a PhD? The MSc program I'm interested in is given in the UK. I think (hope) I'm so good a student, that they would happily take me in.

Well, then there comes the question how to fund the 2nd master's degree.. In general, are master's degrees (fully) funded in the UK? I'm european if that matters. I would also appreciate if you can point me to grant-providing institutions.

Comment: What exactly are the field of your current MSc and the one you're considering? Do you actually _need_ to do the new MSc in order to get the PhD place?

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no funding available for MSc courses in the UK. In some cases there are 1+3 courses (i.e., a 1 year MSc and a 3 year PhD) where the MSc course is funded, but in general this is not the case.

One benefit of this is that the admissions criteria for MSc courses are pretty low. Essentially anyone with a 2i or higher degree classification can find a program willing to accept them.

Comment: Are you sure that EU (but non-UK) nationals pay a higher course fee? I would think that that is not allowed under EU regulations. See e.g. http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/education/university/fees-and-financial-help/index_en.htm

Comment: Do you know if MPhil is ever funded in the UK, or is it comparable to MSc?

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens you appear to be correct that there is no difference in fees. I am still learning about the UK system. I believe, but I cannot find any documentation, that home and EU MSc students cost my department different amounts of money.